# How to trigger NSUserActivity continuation (Universal Links opening) in the current app?

Tags: ios, handoff, ios-universal-links, nsuseractivity

Universal Links in iOS9 use the Handoff mechanism to look at a link in an app instead of the browser: Whenever a Universal Link is clicked, iOS activates the corresponding app and calls `-application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler` with a user activity containing the Universal Link's URL (see [Apple guide on Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html)).

I'd like to trigger this mechanism manually, i.e. creating an `NSUserActivity` instance with a `webpageURL` property and dispatching it to be handled by the current app's `-application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler`. Is there a way to achieve this?

At the moment I'm just calling `-application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler` directly, but this feels wrong and I'd like to implement it in a more proper way.

Comment: Do you need the `application` or `restorationHandler` parameters? If not, you could create a separate method or class to handle the `NSUserActivity`. And then call that method from both `-application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler` or directly from within your app. The documentation says `It’s important to understand that if your app uses openURL: to open a universal link to your website, the link always opens in Safari instead of getting redirected to your app.` so its unlikely there is a way to directly hit that method from within your app.